# how to split up values in json with javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, parsing, jsonparser

i have some code json in here.

```
[ 
    {
      "id": "Node-1",
      "label": "Node-1",
      "image": "img/hosts.png",
      "shape": "image",
      "description": "Node-1:type: OS::Nova::Serverproperties: image: {get_param:image} flavor: {get_param:flavor}"
     },
     {
      "id": "Switch-1",
      "label": "Switch-1",
      "image": "img/switch.png",
      "shape": "image",
      "description": "Switch-1:type: OS::Neutron::Netproperties:   name:Switch-1Switch-1_subnet:"
     }
]
```

how can i get the "description" value with javascript?

Comment: How are you loading the json

Comment: You can assign the Json to a variable and read it as a property in an array. For example: Json[1]. description

Answer (score 0):

Its an Array of JSON objects so you can access those `array objects using index`.[Read more on JavaScript Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

For the Object properties you can use name of property or you can loop through them using `Object.keys or Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`

```js
var x=[ 
    {
      "id": "Node-1",
      "label": "Node-1",
      "image": "img/hosts.png",
      "shape": "image",
      "description": "Node-1:type: OS::Nova::Serverproperties: image: {get_param:image} flavor: {get_param:flavor}"
     },
     {
      "id": "Switch-1",
      "label": "Switch-1",
      "image": "img/switch.png",
      "shape": "image",
      "description": "Switch-1:type: OS::Neutron::Netproperties:   name:Switch-1Switch-1_subnet:"
     }
]
 alert(x[0].description)
```